# Want to profiling web application in JBoss Server in local machine

Tags: java, performance, memory, jboss, profiling

in my local machine I am running an web application in JBoss server. I am using JVisual VM for profiling my application. When I am trying to point/connect to JBoss with JVisual VM, My application is getting tremendously slow or its getting down(not working any more).

I want to do instrumentation profiling to get the actual memory usage for various objects.

OS: Windows 7 Enterprise
Processor: Core 2 Duo @3.00GHz 3.00GHz
RAM: 4.00 GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the JBoss client JAR:

```
jvisualvm.exe -cp:a c:\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\bin\client\jboss-client.jar
```

You will need to modify the JVM security policy:

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=security.policy
```

use the add-user.sh script to add a Management user.

Add a Remote Host in VisualVM and use a JMX Connection with the Management user created above.

Full details on how to setup Visual VM: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/monitoring-wildfly-using-visualvm